# Power bank for gaming laptop

Tags: laptop, power-bank

I have an Aorus X5-MD gaming laptop (Aorus is the gaming division of Gigabyte, and appears to share some hardware, including the power system.) which has an input power specification of 19.5VDC 10.5A, or 200W.

I would like to extend this laptop's battery life - at present I get perhaps two hours, but I'd like at least four.

I'm looking for a slim and *relatively* inexpensive power bank that can supply the necessary current - the voltage doesn't seem to be a problem these days, but 10.5A would likely burn out most if not all typical power banks, most of the highest capacity power banks seem to have a maximum current of 4-5A.

I'd like something that I can put in my backpack and lug around, so relatively flat would be good.

Alternatively, if there was any way of using several lower-power-capacity power banks connected in parallel in such a way that they didn't feed back into one-another and burn out/explode, I'd consider that too.

If the only option is a power bank with mains AC output, it'd have to be Australian 240V 50Hz true sine-wave output(so I can use it for other things), at 300W to allow for conversion losses.

Answer (score 1):

If your AC adapter is 200W, your situation is similar to mine. I have a 120W laptop and 230W gaming laptop, and here are the solutions that I found.

1. [ChargeTech 54000 mAh](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XJ31XZR) at $399 - Top-of-the-line solution that will power any device up to 250W. Still, the price is quite steep!
   This uses a mains AC output, and so I'm unsure about how it works for an Australian output, but the specs say "The international outlets are compatible with Type A, B, C, I, G, E, and L."
2. [Aivant 42000 mAh at $220](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071RC5Y3N)  - Cheaper solution than the above. It worked for my 230W device. The specs say that this supports 200W continuous/250W peak, and so you should be OK.
   This also uses a mains AC output, and so I am unsure about Australian compatibility.

- Devices such as the MAXOAK 50000 mAH WILL NOT WORK! The specs only support up to 90W, but I was able to get my 120W laptop to run. My 230W gaming laptop did not run.

I did a detailed write-up of my testing if you're interested.

[Portable Power Banks for Laptops](http://www.japandude.com/power-options-for-gaming-laptops/)

Comment: I'm quite concerned about the inefficiencies of going from whatever voltage the power bank's battery(s) output all the way up to mains voltage (240v in my case) or even only 110v, and then back down to 19.5v.  I'd rather a device that was designed to supply 20v at 10A, since the battery can be configured to supply around the correct voltage.

Comment: The problem is that, right now, there are just too few options available.
The design you're speaking of is used in the MAXOAK 50000 mAh, which runs by directly connecting to the laptop without an AC adapter, but it didn't work with my 230W laptop (message was displayed indicating not enough power). None of the really small power banks can dish out much power ... yet.
I expect more options to become available moving forward because more and more laptop manufacturers are using the sealed (non-replaceable) battery, which means that demand for high-capacity, high-wattage power banks should grow.

Comment: I'm also considering an ORing harness - you plug a few (preferably identical) power banks into its inputs, and plug the harness into the laptop, and the harness' circuitry shares the load between two or more inputs.  At its most basic, you join the negative wires and attach the positive wires to the inputs of a shottsky oring diode pair, and attach the output to the laptop's positive input pin.  However, diodes have heat dissipation issues, and if one power bank drops out, the other could be fried, so you'd be better off with more complicated circuitry to reduce losses and prevent overloads.